# How to ignore videos with like count disabled while using YouTube Data API V3

Tags: python-3.x, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

In a YouTube search result, some videos have their *likes* hidden. My code fails when it reaches those videos:

`KeyError : 'likeCount'`.

Is there a way to ignore such videos and continue with my iteration?

```py
request = youtube.videos().list(part = "snippet,statistics", id = LIST)
A = request.execute()
for j in range(len(A['items'])):
  Data.append({
    'Views': A['items'][j]['statistics']['viewCount'],
    'Likes': A['items'][j]['statistics']['likeCount'],
    'Dislikes': A['items'][i]['statistics']['dislikeCount']
  })
```

Comment: `'Likes': A['items'][j]['statistics'].get('likeCount')`?

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite your original code as below:

```py
request = youtube.videos().list(
  part = "snippet,statistics",
  id = LIST
)
response = request.execute()
for item in response.get('items', []):
  stat = item['statistics']
  # items without 'like' and 'dislike'
  # count get those counts to be 0
  Data.append({
    'Views': stat.get('viewCount', 0),
    'Likes': stat.get('likeCount', 0),
    'Dislikes': stat.get('dislikeCount', 0)
  })
```

Notice that all statistics data under the `statistics` property of the response obtained from the API is accessed with the `get` method, such that, if the respective property does not exists, then its associated value is taken to be `0`.

Another possibility for your `for` loop above would look as follows:

```
for item in response.get('items', []):
  stat = item['statistics']
  # items without 'like' and 'dislike'
  # counts are being ignored
  if stat.get('likeCount') is None or \
     stat.get('dislikeCount') is None:
       continue
  Data.append({
    'Views': stat['viewCount'],
    'Likes': stat['likeCount'],
    'Dislikes': stat['dislikeCount']
  })
```